# React module not found, The module is installed, but when I run it, it doesn't find it

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs, yarnpkg

```
import Particles from 'react-particles-js';
import Navigation from './components/Navigation/Navigation';
import Logo from './components/Logo/Logo';
import ImageLinkForm from './components/ImageLinkForm/ImageLinkForm';
import Rank from './components/Rank/Rank';

import './App.css';
import 'tachyons';


const ParticlesOptions = {
    particles: {
      line_linked: {
        shadow: {
          enable: true,
          color: "#3CA9D1",
          blur: 5
        }
      }
    }
}


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <Particles params={ParticlesOptions}/> 
     <Navigation/>
     <Logo />
     <Rank />
     <ImageLinkForm />
     {/* <FaceRecognition /> */}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

terminal error:
./node_modules/react-particles-js/cjs/particles.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'tsparticles' in 'C:\Users\admin\Desktop\gitforder\facerecognition\node_modules\react-particles-js\cjs'
Error from chokidar (C:\node_modules): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\DumpStack.log.tmp'

browser error: ./node_modules/react-particles-js/cjs/particles.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'tsparticles' in 'C:\Users\admin\Desktop\gitforder\facerecognition\node_modules\react-particles-js\cjs'

I have this module installed in node_modules.

Comment: is this run in wsl? It looks like the reads from disk are too slow (probably because security checks on the files).

Comment: what is wls? I ran this on windows.

Comment: tsparticles is a peer dependency, you will need to install it.. `npm i tsparticles`

Comment: maybe some other program (antivir) is using the file; restarting your pc might help

Comment: OMG!!!!!! npm i tsparticles <- 
I did it.!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Delete node modules and package-lock.json. careful package-lock.json not package.json
then re-inatall all dependencies with npn install